# C++ calculate average and standard deviation

Tags: c++, vector, average, standard-deviation

I have this program where it asks a user how many values the user will enter in, asks for the values and puts them into a vector.  Then I need to calculate the average and standard deviation.
I have the average part but it looks like something is wrong and I get the wrong average.  And im not too sure how to get started on the standard deviation part.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Create vector
    vector<double> values;

    // Declare variables
    double count;
    double value;
    double average;
    double stdDev;

    // Prompt user and get the number of values
    cout << "How many values will you enter?\n";
    cin >> count;

    // Get the values from user and calculate average
    for( double i = 1; i<= count; i++)
    {
        cin >> value;
        values.push_back(value);
        average+=values[i];
    }
    cout << average/count << '\n';

    //Calculate standard deviation


    return 0;
}
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: `double average;` is uninitialized. It has indeterminate value.

Comment: `double average; => double average = 0;`.  local standard datatypes are not 0 initialized.

Comment: After the first `push_back`, `values[0]` is defined but `values[1]` is not. And so on. Your counting should start at `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `double average = 0;` instead of `double average;`
2. And use `values[i-1]` instead of `values[i]` inside the loop.

Why?

1. You declared average and didn't initialized it. For this it has a value that can't be known before the code executes. When you are adding `value[i]` with `average` that value of `average` is in it. For this you are getting wrong output. You need to add only all `value[i]`. So initialize `average` with 0.
2. Vector indexing is 0 based. So the n-th element inserted to a vector will be found at [n-1]-th position.

Comment: I'm still getting a weird answer.  So ill say ill enter 4 values and just enter 3,3,3,3 and the average is shown as 2.1496e-309.

Comment: @PFKrang this answer is only half your problem, see my comment above.